# Difference between @material-ui vs material-ui (without at-sign)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Just starting (again) with material UI and react.  There are two packages material-ui and @material-ui, which is the best starting point (latest) as of 2019-07 timeframe?

I think it is `npm install @material-ui/core` based on ... https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/.  The GIT repo is at https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui

Simple question, hopefully simple answer.

Other questions I looked at:

- [Use Create-React-App with Material UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44192576/use-create-react-app-with-material-ui) - This answer says to use `npm install --save material-ui` but because it is 2 years old, I think it may be out of date.
- [Difference between Material-Ui and Material-Ui-Next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49403887/difference-between-material-ui-and-material-ui-next)
- [How to install Material-UI Docs WITHOUT installing material-ui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667861/how-to-install-material-ui-docs-without-installing-material-ui)

Comment: As over Material UI version 5, the install uses @mui.  So `npm install @mui/material @mui/styled-engine-sc styled-components` is shown on this page https://mui.com/getting-started/installation/#npm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`@material-ui/core` is the correct one to use for v4. For v5, the equivalent package is `@mui/material`.

If you go to https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui, you'll see that `material-ui` is deprecated. The last stable version in the `material-ui` package was `0.20.2`. For the 1.0 release it moved to `@material-ui/core` and for the stable release of v5 it moved to `@mui/material`.

The `@material-ui` scope (for v4) is used for the following packages that are all managed within the monorepo you referenced (https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/v4.12.3/packages):

- [@material-ui/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/core)
- [@material-ui/icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/icons)
- [@material-ui/styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/styles)
- [@material-ui/system](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/system)
- [@material-ui/lab](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/lab)
- [@material-ui/utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/utils)
- [@material-ui/types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/types)
- [@material-ui/docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/docs)
- [@material-ui/codemod](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/codemod)

Similarly, the `@mui` scope (for v5) is used for the similar set of packages supported for v5 (https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages):

- [@mui/material](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/material)

  - This is the equivalent of `@material-ui/core`
- [@mui/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/core)

  - This is the **NOT** the equivalent of `@material-ui/core`. `@mui/core` is a new package for unstyled (no Material-Design CSS applied) versions of the components.
- [@mui/icons-material](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/icons-material)
- [@mui/styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/styles)

  - This is for supporting the `withStyles` and `makeStyles` JSS-backed styling APIs and is not recommended for use in new projects.
- [@mui/system](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/system)
- [@mui/lab](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/lab)
- [@mui/utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/utils)
- [@mui/types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/types)
- [@mui/docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/docs)
- [@mui/codemod](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/codemod)

Comment: The code I was updating was using v0.x so I found this link helpful... https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v0x/

Comment: And just FYI... If you try just changing `npm install material-ui` with `npm install @material-ui` you'll get an error `Invalid tag name @material-ui: Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.`  The correct usage `npm install @material-ui/core` works without an error!

Comment: [Material-UI is now MUI!](https://mui.com/blog/material-ui-is-now-mui/)

Comment: @x-yuri I've updated my answer to include the v5 `@mui` packages.

Answer (score 3):

The @ scope indicates package ownership

The main advantage of scopes I've seen so far is that each scope is controlled by npm account of an organization / user, much like GitHub usernames / organization names.

This way, it makes it easy to determine if the package you are looking at belongs to an organization you trust, or if it is a third party tool.

For example, if you see:

```
@material-ui
```

then you know that it comes from the **material-ui** team and can be **trusted**.

On the other hand, the same **could not** be said about:

```
material-ui
```

For more https://docs.npmjs.com/about-scopes