# What is the difference between Material-ui/core and material-ui?

Tags: material-ui

I have both libraries in my project, but I keep getting an error: "Can't resolve 'material-ui/core/Table".

Some people told me to delete one dependency, while others suggested me to delete the other one. I am lost at what I should do. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you please include an example of the relevant code?

Comment: You appear to be missing the "@". It should be `@material-ui/core/Table`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between @material-ui vs material-ui (without at-sign)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875498/difference-between-material-ui-vs-material-ui-without-at-sign)

Answer (score 0):

`import { Table } from "@material-ui/core"` or `import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table"`

Both should work fine.