# How to change default colors in material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Looking to change the primary and secondary colors of my application. 
The manual says this is all you need but I am still seeing the basic blue/red default colors in my app. I've been going off this reference https://material-ui.com/customization/color/

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core";
import { MuiThemeProvider } from "material-ui/styles";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#ff8f00"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#ffcc80"
    }
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <App />
  </MuiThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Does [this comment on spectrum](https://spectrum.chat/material-ui/help/muithemeprovider-vs-themeprovider~f6fa2e2b-26d1-45cd-a134-5be0d50ea865?m=MTU1MDc2NTQwMTM4MA==) help you? I'm no MUI expert, so can't help too much, but it seems you should be using `ThemeProvider` now and not `MuiThemeProvider`.

Comment: You are importing MuiThemeProvider from the 0.x version of Material-UI. You should import it from "@material-ui/core/styles" instead.

Comment: Agree with @George, the documentation points to `ThemeProveder`, however from different NPM package

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875498/difference-between-material-ui-vs-material-ui-without-at-sign/56875978#56875978 for more details.

Comment: importing ThemeProvider instead of MuiThemeProvider worked!! Thanks for the responses. I don't know where I read to import MuiThemeProvider..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use the ThemeProvider from the @material-ui/core instead of MuiThemeProvider from @material-ui/styles

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#ff8f00"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#ffcc80"
    }
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <App />
  </ThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to import `import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';` instead of `import { MuiThemeProvider } from "material-ui/styles";` according to the documentation.

[Material-UI documentation example](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#example)

Answer (score 2):

```
`createMuiTheme` is deprecated in newer versions. I used below code to make it work!

import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#3399ff"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#000000"
    }
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <App/>
  </ThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per new updates, you can view the docs at https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/, and follow easily as follows. Now it will work as the MUI has been updated:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { blueGrey } from '@mui/material/colors';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: blueGrey[500],
    },
  },
});

function App() {
  return <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>...</ThemeProvider>;
}
```