# MaterialUI Button Could not override style

Tags: css, reactjs, button, material-ui, styles

Could not override the style using `className` on a `Button`. The same style works correctly on a `TextField`. Using `style` prop allows to override `Button` style.
What am I missing?

Issue link: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-dewdney-r6y8u

***Same Code***:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, TextField } from "material-ui";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  buttonStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "#ADD8E6"
  }
}));

const App = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <Button className={classes.buttonStyle}>Failed Submit</Button>
      <Button style={{ backgroundColor: "#CACACA" }}>Working Submit</Button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <TextField className={classes.buttonStyle} label="Name" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: You are importing `Button` from the wrong package. Please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875498/difference-between-material-ui-vs-material-ui-without-at-sign/56875978#56875978

Comment: It looks like you started changing your sandbox to use `@material-ui/core` instead of `material-ui`; however, you were using the alpha of v5 instead of the stable v4 version. With v4 your code works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-meitner-9u38d?file=/src/App.js.

Comment: Thank you @RyanCogswell, you are correct. After changing the library from `material-ui` to `@material-ui/core` everything worked even for alpha-24 version.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a lot simpler. Create an arbitrary style object:

```
const style = {
  backgroundColor: "#ADD8E6"
};
```

Apply it to your button:

```
<Button style={style}>Failed Submit</Button>
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-poitras-e1s3y?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the material-UI override system,  you can override by using styled-components [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/), which is much simpler

Answer (score -2):

You should use the !important keyboard in the css style.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
 buttonStyle: {
  backgroundColor: "#ADD8E6 !important"
 }
}));
```

Comment: The style works file when applied via `style` prop. Issue is for the "Failed Submit" button. The backgroundColor from buttonStyle is not applied to the "Failed Submit" button.

Comment: I updated the answer, hope this help. you need to add the !important atribute to the json object style.                                                                                         
buttonStyle: {
  backgroundColor: "#ADD8E6 !important"
 }

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any reason why styles using `className` works on many components(eg: `TextField`) , but not on `Button`?

Comment: Well, styles override classes because the class css is loaded first and then the style css is loaded. The reason the class works on the Button probably (you could check in devtools) has an !important in the material-ui css but, your local !important is overriding the themes !important tag... Just speculation but, you could check what material-ui is using to verify.

Comment: I don't have much experience using material-UI, but usually, the style props tend to have more hierarchical relevance than the className, most of the time the style prop doesn't need to use the "!important" keyboard cause the CSS properties are directly applied to the component itself, sorry for my English

Comment: Thank you!. I got into the wrong assumption that whatever we apply using `className` will be the final (I thought the order of class maters as mentioned in https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/20003). But that is not the case, only the order of declaration & specificity matters. The background style on TextField worked, cause that style was not there in MUI class. So it looks like we need to use `!important` in any common styles. For example: margin style on `TextField` cannot be overriden without `!important` when using `className`.